# Firebase Cloud Functions on Client (vue.js) to access Back-End API data hosted on GAE PHP

Tags: php, firebase, google-app-engine, vue.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a web app hosted in Firebase in vue.js. The app access to the organization's main database via API to a back-end server developed in PHP (laravel) hosted in GAE.
I'd like to know if using Firebase Cloud Function on the client (js) to make calls to a back end API (PHP) would help me to protect data and be more efficient authenticating calls from the client to back end.

**Currently**:
Users login into the client using Firebase Auth and the client sends the resulting token to my back-end server on each API call. Then the back-end verifies the token received via HTTPS using FB Auth API and then if verified, the backend would return the request data via JSON back to the client-side via HTTPS response.

My 2 biggest concerns are:

1) would this approach scale well with more users. 
2) for large extractions of data, i.e. 1000+ rows. I'd like to avoid to have JSON objects being "downloaded" on the client.

**New Scenario:**
The users would still log in on the client (vue.js) using FB Auth, but the Client would use FB Cloud Functions to make the calls to the Back-End API data hosted on GAE and then return the data as an array.

The advantages I hope to utilize are:
 - The client will not have https traffic with data as this would be handled by FBCF and send to the client via socket (?).
 - Save verification auth calls from the server, **IF** there is a way for FBCF to make calls to GAE without the need to pass the token (maybe using endpoints?)

Does this make sense or am I introducing a middle man unnecessarily?